# Entity framework4 performance

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I have started working with EF4 recently and I am noticing some bottlenecks in terms of performance that I am finding worrying. I have no more than 400 rows in the tables I am working with below but it takes 4 seconds, using the system diagnostics stopwatch as a timer, to execute both statements below.

I am just looking for opinions on whether or not I am using the framework in the correct manner, as the query performance is substantially slower than it is when I use stored procedures directly.

So, I have structured all my EF queries as follows. Firstly, I bring back the fields I need to work with in an anonymous type, as show below :

```
using (var entities = new MyEntities())
{

    var dbRecords = (from record in entities.MasterRecords
                  select new
                  {
                      ID = record.Id,
                      Name = record.Name,
                      AddressLineOne = record.AddressLineOne,
                      TransactionID = record.TransactionId
                  }).ToList();
```

Next, I call a static method in my business object class to create the object. Note that the repository call in the code below also calls the EF.

```
        var output = from dbrecord in dbRecords
                 select MasterData.CreateNewRecord(
                        this.recordRepository.FindRecords(dbrecord.ID),
                        dbrecord.Name,
                        dbrecord.AddressLineOne,
                        dbrecord.TransactionID
                 ).ToList();

}
```

Am I going about this the correct way?

Comment: First, can you take the `ToList()` off of both queries and see how that affects the performance?  And can you also paste the actual SQL query that is sent over?  With that SQL query, see if it is EF or your SQL server that is the problem by running that same query in Management Studio and see how long it takes

Comment: Does it take 4 seconds each time or just at the first time? EF may require some time for initialization for the first query

Comment: It always takes 4 secs.

Comment: Also, removed the ToList and it makes no difference.

Comment: Apologies for the title error. I have extracted the sql and the queries executes in no time, 0 secs in the Management Studio.

Comment: What is `this.recordRepository` in the second part? Did you measure these two parts separately? Which one takes longer?

Comment: `CreateNewRecord` sounds like it inserts a new record. More, `FindRecords` sounds like another select. It means that you do a select and then you do 400 selects and 400 inserts. More, we don't know what `CreateNewRecord` does internally, maybe it issues some other selects/inserts/updates. Did you try to record how many actual sql statements are executed against the database?

Comment: CreateNewRecord does not hit the database, it just creates a new instance in my Business Object. this.recordRepository.FindRecords does hit the database but it can only returns 10 records for each dbrecord. That will mean that the db will be hit 400 times for each dbrecord. Could that be the issue?